# Android developer About a single choice checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, view

I am implementing a login interface and I have two checkboxes: Male and Female. Now I want the user can only select one of these checkboxes. My .java file is like this:

```
    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
          checMale = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.Male_che);
          checFemale = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.Female_che);

    View.OnClickListener maleChec = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sex = "Male";
                checFemale.setChecked(false);
            }
    };
    View.OnClickListener femaleChec = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sex = "Female";
                checMale.setChecked(false);
            }
    };

    checMale.setOnClickListener(maleChec);
    checFemale.setOnClickListener(femaleChec);
}
```

This does not work anyway. I am a complete beginner. Could you help me with that please?

Comment: What if the user identifies with both genders or neither!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use [Radio Buttons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html) or disable the other checkbox when one is selected using `checMale.setEnabled(false);` or `checFemale.setEnabled(false);`

Also make sure you enable the disabled one when the checked box is unchecked.

```
checMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sex = "Male";
            if(checMale.isChecked()){
                checMale.setChecked(false);
                checFemale.setEnabled(true);
            }else{
                checMale.setChecked(true);
                checFemale.setEnabled(false);
           }  
        }
});
checFemale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sex = "Female";
            if(checFemale.isChecked()){
               checFemale.setCheck(false);
               checkMale.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else{
               checFemale.setCheck(true);
               checkMale.setEnabled(false);
            } 
        }
});
```

Make sure at least one of them is selected before the user proceeds. Radio Buttons are a much better idea.

Comment: And could you tell me why my code does not work? when I select one, the other one is not banned.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Radio Button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html) instead of your checkboxes.